# Is this a good approach for threading and synchronization of multiple functions of a Java class?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a class Prefs, which has various methods. I need to rewrite it using threading and synchronization.

I'm looking at this variant: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html

So currently:

```
class T_readConfigFile extends Thread {
  protected Prefs p = null;
  public T_readConfigFile(Prefs p) {
    this.p =p;
  }

  public void run() {
    p.readConfigFile();
  }
}
```

and

```
 public synchronized void readConfigFile() { ...
```

But somehow making N identical classes for each of the methods I want to thread doesn't look like a good idea. I assume it the entire class in this.p = p; gets loaded into memory — do I really need that if I'll be using only one method from there?

So: this works, but I don't like it, are there better ways?

Comment: The object referred to by `p` is loaded into memory already before the constructor is called.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using threads, anyway?

Comment: I am trying to learn multithreading :)

I will have several methods editing a file, possibly at the same time; I think it would be fitting here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you want to call some method foo() in a background thread.  You have already discovered the most basic way.  Here's a somewhat preferable variation on what you did:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        foo();
    }
}).start();
```

OK, so I wrote six lines of Java code to call one function.  Yes, that's kind of verbose.  Welcome to Java (or at least, Welcome to Java7.  If it can be done more concisely in Java8, I haven't yet learned how.)

This approach has a couple of problems that are worse than verbosity though:

1) You create and destroy a new thread each time you want to call a background method.  Creating and destroying threads is relatively expensive.

2) If the background tasks take significant time to perform relative to how often you invoke them, you have no means to control the number of them that are running at the same time.  In a busy application, it could keep growing until you get an OutOfMemoryError.

A better approach is to use a thread pool:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
...
final int NUM_THREADS = ...;
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
...
executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        foo();
    }
});
```

Each time you submit a new task to the thread pool, it will wake an already existing thread, and the thread will perform the task and then go back to sleep.  No threads are created or destroyed except when the pool starts up.

Also, if all of the threads are busy when you submit the new task, the task will be added to a queue, and it will be performed later when a worker thread becomes available.

This is just a simple example:  The java.util.concurrent package gives you many more options including the ability to limit the size of the queue, the ability to make thread pools that grow or shrink depending on demans, and perhaps most important of all, the ability to wait for a task to complete, and a way to get a return value from a completed task.

Check it out.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-frame.html

Answer (score 0):

A `synchronized` method locks the method's class object so that only one thread can be executing that method at a time. This is useful for situations where you don't want multiple threads to be reading or writing to the same file or stream at the same time, for example.

If you need each thread to read its own separate configuration file, you probably don't need to synchronize the `readConfigFile()` method. On the other hand, you *do* need to synchronize it if every thread reads the *same* config file.

But if all of the threads are reading the *same* config file, perhaps you should only have one thread (or perhaps the main parent thread) read the file once, and *then* pass the resulting parsed config values to each thread. This saves a lot of I/O.